# How to get Paypal Subscribers details? Or full report with cancellation details

Tags: php, paypal

I have downloaded a list of transactions from paypal. Now I want to select the active subscribers only but as I see there is no "cancellation transactions" at all. So according to the report I have 1000 subscribers but on paypal "Recurring payments dashboard" there is only 300 active subscribers. 
So is there a way to get the Subscribers details by API or get the report with cancellation details?